# Batch File - add password protected user accounts and add to a group

Tags: batch-file

I'm currently working on a batch file which would allow me to create a certain number of folders for users, files within those folders for user identification and to create a user account for each user that is password protected and then add all the users to a group.

Now I have managed to create the folders and files using the following code but i'm unsure how I can create password protected user accounts by expanding the code. here is what I got so far,

```
    @echo off
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,5) DO MD Client%%a
for /l %% in (1,1,5) do (cd.>Client%%a.txt) 
for /l %% in (1,1,5) do move Client%%a.txt Client%%a
```

The only part I am struggling with is adding a user account for all 5 of the users, password protect them (it can be a simple password accross the board which the user can change later), and to finally add the 5 user accounts to a new group which the code must create. If anyone knows how to do this, ill be eternally grateful as I am still learning how to write for batch files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
net localgroup myGroup /add
for /l %%a in (1,1,5) do (
    net user Client%%a password
    net localgroup myGroup Client%%a /add
)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code. Just another question, if run in Windows 7, what is the best way of finding out if the accounts/ group were created? I tried going to the accounts page in the control panel but it does not show the newly created accounts. Thanks.

Comment: `net localgroup` will enumerate the groups, `net localgroup groupname` will enumerate the users in the indicated group

Comment: ahh thanks for the help. I thought I had an issue with the code but just ran it in admin mode and it works. Thanks!